# PowerShell .NET Bold text in a textbox

Tags: .net, forms, powershell

Is there a simple way to have the titles like 'Version xx' displayed in bold? It's a bit annoying to start using labels for the titles, as the text will grow in time and has to be re-positioned every time then.

**Code:**

```
$P0Label2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$P0Label2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(8,28)
$P0Label2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(516,340)
$P0Label2.ReadOnly = $True
$P0Label2.WordWrap = $True
$P0Label2.ScrollBars = 'Vertical'
$P0Label2.Multiline = $True
$P0Label2.BackColor = 'LightSteelBlue'
$P0Label2.Text = 
    "Version 2.0:",
    "- 2015/01/05 Stuff",
    "- 2015/01/09 Stuff",
    "Version 1.0:",
    "- 2014/04/25 Stuff" | foreach {"$_`r`n"}
$P0.Controls.Add($P0Label2)
```

Thank you for your help.

**Full solution thanks to Micky below:**

```
$P0Label2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$P0Label2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(8,28)
$P0Label2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(516,340)
$P0Label2.ReadOnly = $True
$P0Label2.WordWrap = $True
$P0Label2.ScrollBars = 'Vertical'
$P0Label2.Multiline = $True
$P0Label2.BackColor = 'LightSteelBlue'
$P0Label2.Text = 
    "Version 2.0:",
    "- 2015/01/05 Stuff",
    "- 2015/01/09 Stuff",
    "Version 1.0:",
    "- 2014/04/25 Stuff" | foreach {"$_`r`n"}

"Version 2.0:",
"Version 1.0:" | foreach {
    $oldFont =  $P0Label2.Font
    $font = New-Object Drawing.Font($oldFont.FontFamily, $oldFont.Size, [Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
    $string = $_
    $P0Label2.SelectionStart = $P0Label2.Text.IndexOf($string)
    $P0Label2.SelectionLength = $string.length
    $P0Label2.SelectionFont = $font
    $P0Label2.DeselectAll()
}
$P0.Controls.Add($P0Label2)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set a textbox's text to bold at run time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089033/how-do-i-set-a-textboxs-text-to-bold-at-run-time)

Comment: Not really, I was more looking for something that allows for more flexibility like `b<text>\b`. But this doesn't work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way of doing it using RichText:

```
$P0Label2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
```

Let's find the used font and make a new version using bold:

```
$oldFont =  $P0Label2.Font
$font = New-Object Drawing.Font($oldFont.FontFamily, $oldFont.Size, [Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
```

Let's now say we want to hightlight `Version V1.0` within your text. We first find its index as part of `$P0Label2.Text`, then we use SelectionStart and SelectionLength to select it, we change the font to a bold version, and we deselect the selection, leaving the text in bold.

```
$string = "Version 1.0"
$P0Label2.SelectionStart = $P0Label2.Text.IndexOf($string)
$P0Label2.SelectionLength = $string.length
$P0Label2.SelectionFont = $font
$P0Label2.DeselectAll()
```

So it's not based on tags, but it can be a start to work something out.

Comment: Thank you Micky, is there maybe a typo? As I'm getting the error: `New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "3" argument(s): "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: family"`

Comment: Interesting, try `$oldFont = $P0Label2.Font`, should work too.

Comment: Correct, I also had to change to `$P0Label2.Font = $font`. Now there are no errors anymore. However, it's all in bold now.. :P

Comment: Yes don't change `$P0Label2.Font` as that is your normal font, change only `$P0Label2.SelectionFont`.

Comment: Ohh forgot one line of code : `$P0Label2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox`, sorry forgot that. To be able to use the approach above you need a RichTextBox.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you :) Post updated with the full solution I used.